# Passing value of a local variable to field

Tags: java, class, object

I am new to the Java, and I am doing an assignment for a school, but I got stuck at the very fundamentals it seems.

My first class is as follows:

```
public class Publisher {

    private String name;
    private String state;

    public Publisher(){}

    public Publisher(String name, String state) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }


}
```

In the first class, I had two fields, whose values were changed via constructors, and can only be accessed using getters. I also had another constructor, which I used for creating object in next class.

Here is my other class:

```
public class Book {

    private String bookName;
    private String language;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Publisher publisher = new Publisher();
        String publisherName=publisher.getName();

    }



    public Book(String bookName, String language) {
        super();
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.language = language;
    }



    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }



}
```

In a second class, I essentialy want to do all the same things as in first one, with a difference that I want to use the object name of a Publisher class as a third field. In my newbie thinking, I thought of solving the matter as shown in a code, but I don't know if I can somehow use a local variable of main method as an instance variable.

I have a feeling I am doing beginner's mistake somewhere, so any advice or solution would be welcomed.

Comment: Maybe you need to pass in the instance of `Publisher` to the `Book` constructor and set it to a instance variable (just like you do with `bookName` and `language`).

Comment: If you create an instance of `Book` you can pass your local `String` into the constructor.

Comment: Why do you have that second constructor that allows to create an unnamed and stateless `Publisher`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want third field, you should first make it. Then you should perform assignment in every object that you create(in constructor for example), otherwise it will be `null`.

```
public class Book {
    private final String bookName;
    private final String language;
    private final Publisher publisher; //third field

    public Book(String bookName, String language, Publisher publisher) {
        super();
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.language = language;
        this.publisher = publisher; //assignment of new field
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public String getPublisher() { //new getter
        return publisher;
    }
}
```

In fact, in your code, all that you do is create local variable that stops its existence after end of `main` method. You should use `main` to test your classes, but for things like assignment it wouldn't have any effect. Also i used here `final` modificator because we should *avoid mutability*(you can learn about it).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand now what to do

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add another field to `Book`, which stores a reference to the publisher - exactly the same way you have `bookName` and `language`.

Also, I would recommend moving your `main` method to a new class with nothing else, to keep it simpler.

```
public class Book {

    private String bookName;
    private String language;
    private Publisher publisher; // <--- NEW

    public Book(String bookName, String language, Publisher publisher) { // <--- NEW PARAMETER
        super();
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.language = language;
        this.publisher = publisher; // <--- NEW
    }

    // main removed (add it to another class)

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    // NEW METHOD
    public Publisher getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you're writing `Publisher publisher = new Publisher();` in your main method, you're just creating an instance of `Publisher` but if you use `Publisher` as an instance variable(field) in your `Book` class, you can use it every time you create a `Book` instance.

For example if your Book class is like this

```
public class Book {

    private String bookName;
    private String language;
    private Publisher publisher;

    public Book(String bookName, String language, Publisher publisher) {
        super();
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.language = language;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public Publisher getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }
}
```

You can create `Book` class anywhere and use the field 'publisher' in it to refer to a `Publisher` object as shown.

```
Book b = new Book();
b.publisher = new Publisher(); // or any method that returns 'Publisher' type object.
```

**Update:** Even though you can access `publisher` reference in the above way, it is not a good practice. You have to encapsulate your fields and access them using setters and getters. (See the constructor and getter method for Publisher)

Comment: By declaring the field public and by manipulating the field directly within outside classes, you increase code coupling and decrease cohesion, two bad things.

Comment: I know but I'm only trying to answer what the question asked and not 'good programming practices'.

Comment: But there are better answers here that don't make the same mistake.